# Plotting waveform in circular path

Tags: audiokit

Trying to plot file waveform in circular form and looking through the underlying EZAudio's EZAudioPlot class [docs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/EZAudio/0.6.0/Classes/EZAudioPlot.html#//api/name/createPathWithPoints:pointCount:inRect:) tells me this should be possible. However I can't quite wrap my head how to construct the 'points' argument in the linked method. Anyone done this and could point to correct way?

**UPDATE:**

Looking into this I think I've gotten fairly good grasp how EZAudioPlotting works. The actual waveform drawing is done on EZAudioPlotWaveformLayer which is just simple CAShapeLayer subclass. On creation of EZAudioPlot one EZAudioPlotWaveformLayer is created and reference stored on EZAudioPlot class waveformLayer property.

The actual waveform is CGPath on EZAudioPlotWaveformLayer class and to manipulate it it should go something like below.

```swift
// Setup audio data for the plot
let file = EZAudioFile(url: url)
guard let data = file?.getWaveformData(withNumberOfPoints: pointCount) else {return}

// Setup the plot
let waveform = EZAudioPlot()
waveform.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)
waveform.gain = 10.0
// + any other property tweaking you need

//Get hold of the underlaying layer
let myLayer = waveform.waveformLayer!

// Create the default presentation for the waveforms as CGPath
let path = waveform.createPath(withPoints: waveform.points, pointCount: pointCount, in: EZRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: view.bounds.height)).takeRetainedValue()

// ??? Here somehow tweak the CGPath eg. into circular shape ???
newPath = plotPointsIntoCircleOrSomeOtherNiftyFunc(path)

// Stick new path to layer
myLayer.path = newPath
```

Only thing is that currently I haven't figured any math to actually implement anything meaningful at that pseudo code point

Comment: There is no math involved. Just use the CoreGraphics API and draw Circles or Arcs instead of BezierPaths, even tho BezierPaths can do the job as well.